# How to create RAM disk with Golang and in a platform-independent way?

Tags: go, memory, cross-platform, mount, ramdisk

RAM disk can be created in command line with different commands on different operating systems.
For example, to create a RAM disk of 512MB ---

On macOS:

```
diskutil eraseVolume HFS+ "RAMDisk" `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://1048576`
```

On Ubuntu:

```
mkdir /mnt/ramdisk
mount -t tmpfs -o size=512m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

Is there any cross-platform method/way to create a RAM disk in Golang?

Comment: Not in the standard library. You may find 3rd party lib for it, or implement platform-specific behavior using build constraints.

Comment: https://github.com/mroth/ramdisk